# Boot Error in Xubuntu

Tags: system-installation

My laptop computer's CPU doesn't support PAE.
So I tried to install Xubuntu.

I use USB Boot for installtion. Succesful boot.
I chose Default(Maybe Graphic Mode). Then screen Cracked.

Ofcourse I tried to Textmode Installation at another Linux(Backtrack5)

I could use x windows and also start Install. But It changes same when I finish the installation, reboot and start it.
I tried Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Mini Ubuntu, Backtrack5R3. But all the same. Cracked Screen.

CPU : Intel Pentium M 725 1.6

Graphic card : NVIDIA Geforce FX Go5200 64MB

RAM : 1GB DDR

Sorry for my bad English...

Comment: Which versions did you try?

Comment: I think it would be wise to check the following question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: when I press the shift key to get grub menu?

Comment: Keep pressing the shift key repeatedly from the moment you power up your computer until grub menu appears. Don't worry about your English, just be as clear as you can.